# Retrieve SSL Certificate with Zend Http Request and Response

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, zend-http-client

I'm trying to connect to a third party API and I'm using the Zend 1.7.0 framework to access it.  To authenticate, I have to first check an SSL certificate returned from a URL.  This is what I'm doing in my code.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
$response = $client->request('GET');
```

The response is always OK, and when I navigate to '$url' I can see the certificate if I click on the lock in the bottom right corner of my browser window.

Is there a way to access the certificate's owner, expiration date and other properties via the response object?  Do I have to do anything special to the request before sending it to obtain the information about the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the standard connection adaptor that Zend_Http_Client uses.  I did a bit of digging and it looks like the adaptor uses fsockopen which pretty much hide what you're looking for.  The way to do it is to open the socket yourself and get the certificate first:

```
$url = 'mail.google.com'; // For example
$context = stream_context_create();
$res = stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'capture_peer_cert', true);
$res = stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_host', true);
if ($socket = stream_socket_client("tls://$url:443/", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context)) {
    if ($options = stream_context_get_options($context)) {
        if (isset($options['ssl']) && isset($options['ssl']['peer_certificate'])) {
            $keyinfo = openssl_x509_parse($options[$wrapper]['peer_certificate']);
            var_dump($keyinfo);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: This definately led me in the right direction.  Thank you so much!  Where did you find this code?  I googled it and this page came up as the highest index.

Comment: I had to hunt around a lot. I eventually found a bit of code in a newsgroup post that could extract the certificate and then a separate one that showed how to extract the public key, the php.net openssl docs showed how to get the info.  The rest was trial and error.

I should really link back to the sources but I can't remember where the hell I found them all.